# Asymptotical distribution of $\dfrac{\hat{\mu_n}-\mu}{\hat{\sigma_n}}$

Tags: statistics, random-variables, asymptotics

Let $X_1, ..., X_n$ ($n\ge 2$) be random samples from the double exponential distribution $\mathrm{DE}(\mu, \sigma)$ whose pdf is given by $f(x)= \dfrac{1}{2\sigma}e^{-|x-\mu|/\sigma}$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$. Here $-\infty<\mu<\infty$ and $\sigma>0$.

Now define the sample median $\hat{\mu_n}$ and sample mean absolute deviation $\hat{\sigma_n}$ as follows: $$\hat{\mu_n}=X_{([n/2])}, \hat{\sigma_n}= \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^{n}|X_i-\hat{\mu_n}|$$

Question: What is the asymptotic distribution of $\sqrt n \dfrac{\hat{\mu_n}-\mu}{\hat{\sigma_n}}$ as $n \to \infty$?

My attempt: Using delta method, I figured out that the asymptotic distribution of $\sqrt n (\hat{\mu_n}-\mu)$ is the normal distribution $\mathrm N(0, \sigma^2)$. However, I have no idea how to deal with the distribution of $\hat{\sigma_n}$. I'd like to prove that $\hat{\sigma_n}$ converges in probability to some constant, so that I can deduce the distribution of $\sqrt n \dfrac{\hat{\mu_n}-\mu}{\hat{\sigma_n}}$ using Slutsky's theorem.

Edit: By symmetry of the distribution, the median of the population is $\mathrm E[X]=\mu$.

Therefore, $\hat{\mu_n}\to\mu$ in probability.

Now it remains to prove that $\hat{\sigma_n}\to\sigma$ in probability.

Consider the inequality $$\dfrac 1n \sum_{i=1}^n |X_i - \mu|-\dfrac 1n \sum_{i=1}^n |\hat{\mu_n}-\mu| \le \hat{\sigma_n}\le \dfrac 1n \sum_{i=1}^n |X_i - \mu|+\dfrac 1n \sum_{i=1}^n |\hat{\mu_n}-\mu|$$

Since $X_i$'s are iid random variables, $\dfrac 1n \sum_{i=1}^n |X_i - \mu|\to \mathbb E[|X-\mu|]=\sigma$ in probability by LLN, but I can't apply LLN to $\dfrac 1n \sum_{i=1}^n |\hat{\mu_n}-\mu|$ since $\hat{\mu_n}$'s are not iid.

Does anyone have ideas? I appreciate your help!

Comment: If you know that $\hat{\mu}_n \xrightarrow{p} \mu$, you can count on LLN to show that $\hat{\sigma}_n \xrightarrow{p} \mathbb{E}[|X - \mu|] = \sigma$.

Comment: @SangchulLee Thanks for your comment! I proceeded further, but I still have some troubles. Please see the edited question.

Comment: It is much simpler. You have $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} |\hat{\mu}_n - \mu| = |\hat{\mu}_n - \mu| \xrightarrow{p} 0$.

Comment: @SangchulLee Oh I thought that the summand depends on $i$. Thanks!